# Dynamic form creation in Angular based on server's response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-forms

I am trying to create dynamic forms based on servers response. For example, I have 8 buttons, and each button when clicked should generate a different questionnaire with different input types. The questions for each category are grabbed from the back-end and each question has its type along with it, which could be radio, select etc. Based on this information, how can I generate forms for a specific question set depending what button a user clicks. One thing I thought of was to use ng-hide/show depending on what category is clicked but that would be a really bad practice as there are in total 64 questions for the 8 categories(8 each). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

The response is like:

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "data": {
    "id": "598ca3dac405bc378fc21764",
    "question_set_number": "QS1",
    "questions": [
      {
        "answers": [
          "Answer 1",
          "Answer 2",
          "Answer 3"
        ],
        "id": "59839d20c405bc411540a11d",
        "question_number": "Q1",
        "question_text": "Test question",
        "type": "radio"
      },
      {
        "answers": [
          "Answer 1",
          "Answer 2",
          "Answer 3"
        ],
        "id": "59839d2dc405bc411540a11e",
        "question_number": "Q2",
        "question_text": "Test question",
        "type": "check"
      }
    ]
  },
  "message": "successful",
  "status": "success"
}
```

Comment: I can make an example for you, but you can loop through inputs, and assign their type dynamically based on the server's response. I have an existing example [here](https://github.com/kauffmanes/acoma-data-app/blob/master/public/newFindForm/new-find-form.html), if you think that's what you need.

Comment: Is your response similar to  mine? I just edited my post if you can have a look. Thanks!!

Comment: Yeah it's pretty similar. I'm working on a bin for you. Is this the response of 1 out of the 8 forms? Each button click fires a new service call for questions?

Comment: Yup this response is for 1 out of the 8 question sets. Depending on what a user clicks, it calls a service using that specific question set number. For example button1 would call api/QS1. Button 2 would call api/QS2 and so on. And thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through form inputs based on the server input and display them dynamically like this (working example [here](http://jsbin.com/bujuyod/edit?html,js,output)).

**HTML**

```
<!-- click a button to see a form -->
<button data-ng-click="getQuestions('qs1')">Form 1</button>
<button data-ng-click="getQuestions('qs2')">Form 2</button>
<button data-ng-click="getQuestions('qs3')">Form 3</button>

<form action="">
  <input data-ng-repeat="item in questions" type={{item.type}}>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

  $scope.questions = [];

  $scope.getQuestions = function (category) {

    //make service call based on category and return questions
    //$scope.questions = result of service

    //stubbed for example:
    $scope.questions = [
      {
        "answers": [
          "Answer 1",
          "Answer 2",
          "Answer 3"
        ],
        "id": "59839d20c405bc411540a11d",
        "question_number": "Q1",
        "question_text": "Test question",
        "type": "radio"
      },
      {
        "answers": [
          "Answer 1",
          "Answer 2",
          "Answer 3"
        ],
        "id": "59839d2dc405bc411540a11e",
        "question_number": "Q2",
        "question_text": "Test question",
        "type": "checkbox" //this was check, needed to be checkbox - either update service or manipulate it on your end
      }
    ];

  };


}]);
```

Doing just this shows the concept of displaying the inputs dynamically, while only writing one input field. You add more to it, if the service sends it. If you're going to be handling multiple input types, I recommend making a simple dynamic input directive to handle all of this logic, and then simple pass the type into the directive. I have a working example [here](https://github.com/kauffmanes/acoma-data-app/tree/master/public/components/newFindQuestion), but that's the concept. I can help you with that logic as well.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!! :) I am able to generate questions with single input type for now, but I am just wondering wouldn't this work for multiple input types too? As you are binding the type from the server. Why would I need a directive for that? Thanks again!!

Comment: I guess you wouldn't need to if you're keeping this simple. I used a directive for my project because I had textareas, text, dates... and some were auto-populated with values. It got really large, so it made sense for me to break it out into a directive. But not necessary!

Comment: One thing, as these input types are generated at run time, how do you assign them to ng-model to be submitted to the backend? Each time the questions or answers would be different and could be representing different objects. How do you handle all that with this approach? Thanks!

Comment: What I did was create an object called $scope.formData to hold all of the model data. Then I submitted this object. To actually assign it to the model, you need to call it something unique from the rest of the models, like the ID. `<input data-ng-model="formData[item.id]"> I made a bin [here](http://jsbin.com/kihutak/edit?html,js,output). Also, my working example in my app for more reference is [here](https://github.com/kauffmanes/acoma-data-app/blob/master/public/components/newFindQuestion/question.html) if my bin is too simplistic.

Comment: I was able to generate the form that i was desiring with your help, but I would need one last help please. When my input type is radio, my inputs get generated okay, but when i switch from one radio button to another it doesnt switch. All that it does is select the new value too and keeps adding radio button values instead of switching between them. If you see your bin too, and change the checkbox to radio. You have two radio buttons. Try choosing one, and then the other. It selects both, instead of switching between them. How will i fix this? Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: It is probably choosing both because they are separate items in the collection. One radio button for each section. If you want them to change, you'd need two radio buttons per section. That's a little more complicated. I did a bin [here](http://jsbin.com/bujuyod/edit?html,js,output) to show it. You'll need to update your service response if you can, to show options for each radio button.